# prettier js version 2.8.8 // what is the minimum require node js?

Tags: node.js, npm, prettier

If I'm looking into https://github.com/prettier/prettier/blob/2.8.8/package.json#L15
I can see "engines": { "node": ">=14"}

but If I'm looking inside the installed version of prettier 2.8.8
I see inside package.json

"engines": { "node": ">=10.13.0" },

[image]

Answer (score 0):

10.13.0 for v2.8.8, since that's that they shipped to [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier?activeTab=code). They're most likely different due to dev dependencies.

In the [build script](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/blob/2.8.8/scripts/build/build.mjs#L136) for v2.8.8, the node version is being explicitly set:

```js
packageJson.engines.node = ">=10.13.0";
```

Eventually, v3.0.0 will have `{ "node": ">=14"}`, in the [build script](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/blob/main/scripts/build/build-package-json.js#L38).